# Error when creating Site from Custom Template

Tags: site-template, site

I am receiving the following error when I attempt to creat a new site and use my custom template (that I have used before).  Can you assist?

The error is:

> The site template requires that the feature {xxxxx} be activated in
>   the site collection.

Thanks, Rita

Comment: How are you creating the new site? Programmatically or through UI?

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from "FeatureDependencies" defined in the site template - when creating a site from a template, SharePoint will throw the above error if you're missing any feature dependencies.

You can either try deactivating features and re-creating the site template, or you can perform the following manual steps:
1. Rename the site template to .cab
2. Unpack the .cab
3. Search the .xml files in the archive for FeatureDependency entries and remove as needed.
4. Rebuild the .WSP file (requires generating a manifest and then building a .CAB from the manifest)

I've done the manual approach before - not fun, but technically an option. I'd recommend just trying to rebuild the site template with less activated features.

Answer (score 0):

The features which are active while taking the custom template, must be active while creating new site with that custom template.